# How to get dynamic value in session.get() method in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch some data in hbernate and is using session.get() method where I am passing first argument of class, and second I want to pass integer value say id.

```
try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            System.out.println("isValidEmployerByEmaildId is fetcheched");            
            emp = session.get(Employer.class, 18);                                                        
            System.out.println("Employee Loggedin Successfully.");           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I am passing the id value statically but I want to pass it dynamically. I have pojo class where id is stored but when I am using the get method of pojo class it is returning null pointer exception.

Please help....Thanks in advance

Comment: the NPE could be thrown from trying to access the id field while your POJO object is null. Or it could be the id field of your said POJO contains null value. Debug your code.

Comment: So How can I set access id dynamically.....Is there any possible way?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you looking to replace the number "18" in your sample code with the value of a variable?

Comment: Yes... I want that in that place whatever value is stored in my db should be there.